# Produce Predictive Margins in Statsmodels Output for Logistic Regression

Tags: python, stata, logistic-regression, statsmodels

I've used the `get_margeff()` function to try to generate margins for a logit model I've run. Here is the data and code:

```py
model_5a_1 = smf.logit('''fluid ~ C(examq3_n, Treatment(reference = 2.0)) + C(pmhq3_n) + C(fluidq3_n) + C(mapq3_n, Treatment(reference = 3.0)) + 
                  C(examq6_n, Treatment(reference = 2.0)) + C(pmhq6_n) + C(fluidq6_n) + C(mapq6_n, Treatment(reference = 3.0)) +
                  + C(case, Treatment(reference = 2))''',
                 data = case1_2_vars).fit()

print(model_5a_1.summary())
```

[image]

I'd like to now calculate the margins, much like you can with the `margin` command in Stata. This is as far as I'm getting:

```
margins_5a_1 = model_5a_1.get_margeff(at = 'mean', dummy = True, count = True)
margins_5a_1.summary()
```

[image]

And I'd like to see the actual margins instead of `dy/dx`. Is there a way to do this in statsmodels?

Here is my data set. In this regression I'm only regressing on `fluid` and all variables to the left of `fluid` are the independent variables (those to the right will be used for other logit models).
[image]

And I've tried `get_prediction` like so:

```
model_5a_1.get_prediction(exog = case1_2_vars[['examq3_n', 'pmhq3_n', 'examq3_n', 'pmhq3_n', 'fluidq3_n', 'mapq3_n', 
                                               'examq6_n', 'pmhq6_n', 'fluidq6_n', 'mapq6_n', 'fluid']])
```

But I get `PatsyError: categorical data cannot be >1-dimensional`

Comment: What do you mean with "actual margins"? What's the corresponding Stata command? The margeff result should be the marginal effect switching a dummy from 0 to 1, AFAIR.

Comment: statsmodels does not support multicolumn marginal effects, e.g changing mapq6 in all columns at the same time

Comment: Like where the output looks like this. https://stats.oarc.ucla.edu/stata/dae/using-margins-for-predicted-probabilities/ with the margins for each independent variable. If it’s not possible in statsmodels, do you know if it works for scikit-learn logit?

Comment: Ok, those are predicted means and not marginal effects. Those are covered by `get_prediction` in version 0.14, but only for user specified `exog`. GLM already has get_prediction.

Comment: Currently statsmodels cannot process the formula information to create multi-column or multi-term marginal effects or automatic grids for those in predict. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/8439

Comment: Thank you for the information. Are there any examples on either the statsmodels documentation or elsewhere of `get_prediction`?

Comment: Or more specifically, how I would apply that in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a function to replicate the output that is obtained in Stata. All you need to do is to clearly state the name of your dataframe, name of the dummy variable, the dependent variable, and link to the results of the logit (or OLS) regressions to run it successfully. See below:

```html
def marginsat0_1(dataname, dummy, y, result):
    testflag0 = dataname.copy()
    testflag0[dummy]=0
    testflag0['prob0'] = result.predict(testflag0)
    mean0 = round(testflag0.prob0.mean(),5)
    testflag1 = dataname.copy()
    testflag1[dummy]=1
    testflag1['prob1'] = result.predict(testflag1)
    mean1 = round(testflag1.prob1.mean(),5)
    diff = round((mean1-mean0),5)
    print("Pr(" + str(y) + ")|"+ str(dummy) + "=0 : {}".format(mean0),
          "Pr(" + str(y) + ")|"+ str(dummy) + "=1 : {}".format(mean1),
          "Difference: {}".format(diff), sep="\n")
```